# How to Unit Test Standard Platform Event in Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, platform-event, developer

I have a trigger on FOStatusChangedEvent, which is a standard event in Salesforce triggered when the FulfillmentOrder status is triggered. I need some help on how to unit test the standard platform event in Salesforce.

Trigger Code

```
trigger OSF_FOStatusChangedEventTrigger on FOStatusChangedEvent(after insert) {
    new OSF_FOStatusChangedEventTriggerHandler().run();
}
```

Trigger Handler Code:

```
public with sharing class OSF_FOStatusChangedEventTriggerHandler extends OSF_TriggerHandler {
    /**********************************************************************************************
     * @description  : Initializes a map of FOStatusChangedEvent records with their corresponding record Ids
     * @param        : Map<Id, FOStatusChangedEvent> fOStatusChangedEventNewMap - the map of FOStatusChangedEvent records with their corresponding record Ids
     ***********************************************************************************************/
    private Map<Id, FOStatusChangedEvent> fOStatusChangedEventNewMap;

    /**********************************************************************************************
     * @description Constructor for OSF_FOStatusChangedEventTriggerHandler class
     * @param  : None
     ***********************************************************************************************/
    public OSF_FOStatusChangedEventTriggerHandler() {
        this.fOStatusChangedEventNewMap = (Map<Id, FOStatusChangedEvent>) Trigger.newMap;
    }

    /**********************************************************************************************
     * @description Executes the necessary actions after inserting a FOStatusChangedEvent record.
     * @param  None
     *********************************************************************************************/
    public override void afterInsert() {
        generatePickingSlip(this.fOStatusChangedEventNewMap);
    }

    /**********************************************************************************************
     * @description Given a map of FOStatusChangedEvent records, generates a picking slip batch for the new FOStatusChangedEvent
     * @param fOStatusChangedEventNewMap A map of FOStatusChangedEvent records with their Ids as keys
     *********************************************************************************************/
    private void generatePickingSlip(Map<Id, FOStatusChangedEvent> fOStatusChangedEventNewMap) {
    }

}
```

I tried the test method below to trigger the events but still no luck.
Test Method

```
@isTest
static void testAfterInsert() {
// Test when FOStatusChangedEvent NewStatus is 'Allocated'
    FOStatusChangedEvent fOStatusChangedEvent = new FOStatusChangedEvent();
    fOStatusChangedEvent.NewStatus = 'Allocated';
    Test.startTest();
    // Publish test event
    Database.SaveResult sr = EventBus.publish(fOStatusChangedEvent);
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Comment: hi @chanpelayo, what have you tried? And what issues did you encounter that stopped you from continuing?

Comment: Hi @Adam, my apologies to not included the test method that I've created. I already updated the question with the test method but still no luck.

Comment: It looks like you are missing some required fields in the event ..[see doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_fostatuschangedevent.htm)

Comment: As @cropredy mentioned, `NewStatusCategory` is required.

if you log the save result, you will see

`REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING;You must enter a value: NewStatusCategory`